# What is difference between 2 functions

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I noticed below styles of writing function in F#

```
let reverse1 a =
    a |> List.rev

let reverse2 = function
    | _ as a -> a |> List.rev
```

Can you please explain the difference in them ?

Comment: One reverses a list, the other takes an argument, ignores it, and returns a function value for `List.rev`. Apples and horses, not even apples and oranges.

Comment: Ignore implementation in above functions, its just to show style of function declaration in F#. More refined question is what is difference in declaration style and in what scenario each style is useful ?

Comment: I updated the question.  Is that what you meant to ask?

Comment: Yes, thanks for update.

Comment: @gradbot Why `_ as a` (instead of just `a`)?

Comment: @sepp2k I guess _ as a is same to |a -> a |> List.rev

Comment: Changing his question as little as possible.  It's identical in this case.

Comment: @ildjarn the second doesn't ignore it's argument at all ; it matches anything (with wildcard) naming/aliasing that match : "a" (`as a`) ; I agree it's a bit useless (that's the same as `| a ->`) (as stated by @Saty )

Comment: @Sehnsucht : That's because the question was edited. Look at the edit history and you will find the context is a bit more sensical. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn oh I see :) sorry then, didn't think of verifying history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding "style of function declaration" (as clarified in the comments), there is no real difference in principle. The second definition is just a shortcut.

The first definition straight up defines a function. In your example, it take argument `a`, applies function `List.rev` to it, and returns the result.

The second definition is really a shortcut for defining a function whose body is just one `match` expression.

In other words, if you have a function with body consisting of a `match` expression, like this:

```
let f x = 
    match x with
    | Blue a -> a + 5
    | Green b -> b.SomeField
```

You can write it a bit shorter like this:

```
let f = function
  | Blue a -> a + 5
  | Green b -> b.SomeField
```

To put it in yet other words, `= function` is equivalent to `x = match x with`.

This notation mimics the way you would define segmented functions in mathematics. You may have seen something like this in your high school (or college) maths class:

```
abs(x) =  x,  x >= 0
         -x,  x < 0
```

Answer (score 2):

They are all the same.

```
// as normal function
let reverse1 a = a |> List.rev
let reverse2 a = List.rev a
let reverse3   = List.rev

// as pattern matching
let reverse4   = function | _ as a -> a |> List.rev     // takes everything _ as a, and feeds a into List.rev
let reverse5   = function   _ as a -> a |> List.rev

// as lambda function
let reverse6   = fun a -> a |> List.rev
```